# Issue Mapbox Filters custom icons

Tags: javascript, filter, icons, mapbox

i have this webapp:

http://ftp.escape.pe/mapa-robos/test.html

The icons looks good, but the filter menu doesn't work, the console says:

---

ReferenceError: markers is not defined

markers.setFilter(function(f) {

---

And this is parte of the javascript:

```
$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
// For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.
var filter = $(this).data('filter');
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
markers.setFilter(function(f) {
    // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
    // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
    // a value set to true based on the filter name.
    return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
});
return false;
```

});

Please, anybody can help me =(

PD. Sorry for my english =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is explanatory here.

```
ReferenceError: markers is not defined
```

You are trying to reference a variable, `markers`, which is not defined. So you called your featureLayer something else. Scroll up a bit, and see

```
var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
```

Your featureLayer is called `myLayer`. Instead of saying

```
markers.setFilter(function(f) {
```

You'll need to say

```
myLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
```